# How to wrap an element around an inline element with inline pseudoelements without using absolute positioning

Tags: css

I'd like to wrap a container around my inline elements, so I can place them wherever I want and apply a background color.

I have two inline block elements, of which the inner inline-block element has two pseudo elements which are also inline.
When I try to wrap this with an inline element or an inline-block element the background I apply is only applied to the text width of the non psuedo element, and the :before and :after containers are ignored.

[image: how it's rendered]

How can this be resolved without absolute positioning? Ideally, i'd have the background color encompass all the child (pseudo) elements.

```css
span {
background: green ;
}
.wrap {
  white-space:nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
}
.content:after,.content:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1em;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  background: red;
}
.content {
   display:inline-block;   
}
```

```html
<span>
  <div class="wrap">
     <div class="content">
        foo bar baz
      </div>
  </div>
</span>
<BR/>
<span>
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="content">
        foo bar baz foo bar 
      </div>
  </div>
</span>
<BR/>
<span>  
  <div class="wrap">
      <div class="content">
        foo bar bazfoo bar baz foo bar baz
      </div>
  </div>
</span>
```

Comment: the issue is the 50% of width, you have having an overflow since 2*50% + content > 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that you want the red area to be equal to the green one. CSS grid can do this using the `fr` unit like below:

```css
.content:after,
.content:before {
  content: " ";
  height: 1em;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  display: inline-grid;
  white-space: nowrap;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  align-items: center;
  background: green;
  margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  foo bar baz
</div>
<br>

<div class="content">
  foo bar baz foo bar
</div>
<br>
<div class="content">
  foo bar bazfoo bar baz foo bar baz
</div>
```